# Deck of Cards issue -Java

Tags: java

I am having problems getting this DeckOfCards class to compile. It keeps telling me that it cannot find the symbol when pointing to `Deck2.Shuffle()` and `Deck2.deal()`. Any ideas why?

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards {
    private Cards[] Deck;
    private int cardHold;

    public DeckOfCards() {
        Deck = new Cards[52];
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
                Deck[n] = new Cards(i, j);
                n = n + 1;
            }
        }
        cardHold = -1;
    }

    public void Shuffle() {
        // shuffles ands resets deck
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 52) {
            int rando = (int) (5.0 * (Math.random()));
            Cards temp = Deck[rando];
            Deck[rando] = Deck[i];
            Deck[i] = temp;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public Cards deal() {
        // if there are any more cards left in the deck, return the next one and
        // increment
        // index; return null if all the cards have been dealt
        // ***Question, increment before or
        // after??***----------------------------------------
        if (!hasMoreCards()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Cards temp = null;
            temp = Deck[cardHold];
            cardHold = cardHold + 1;
            return temp;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasMoreCards() {
        // returns true if there are more cards left, else return false
        if (cardHold == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeckOfCards Deck2 = new DeckOfCards();
        Deck2.Shuffle();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            System.out.println(Deck2.deal());
    }
}
```

Below class is Card class, maybe that is causing the issue?

```
public class Cards {
    protected int rank;
    protected int suit;
    protected String[] sNames = { "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds" };
    protected String[] rNames = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8",
            "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

    public Cards(int Rank, int Suit) {
        suit = Suit;
        rank = Rank;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("Your card is: " + rNames[rank - 1] + " of " + sNames[suit - 1]);
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Tip: rename shuffle and other methods so first letter is lowercase. Avoids confusion with ClassNames.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, thanks. But the problem still persists

Comment: "Cannot find a symbol" is usually an indication it can't find something. Such as the method.

Comment: Your class works fine. I just tested it in Eclipse. The imports weren't necessary. There must be an issue elsewhere.

Comment: Yea, as stated in 2 other comments now, I had a dumb error on my part which I solved. I have other non-compiler issues now which I believe I may be able to fix myself.

And the imports were a precaution.

Comment: What was the error so others can learn ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler issues are behind you, but there are lots of issues with your code.

```
public class DeckOfCards {
    private Cards[] deck;
    private int cardHold;

    public DeckOfCards() {
        deck = new Cards[52];
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
                deck[n] = new Cards(i, j);
                n = n+1;
            }
        }
        cardHold = -1;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 52) {
            int rando = (int) (5.0*(Math.random()));
            Cards temp = deck[rando];
            deck[rando] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = temp;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public Cards deal() {
        return (hasMoreCards() ? deck[++cardHold] : null);
    }

    public boolean hasMoreCards() {
        return (cardHold != 0);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeckOfCards deck2 = new DeckOfCards();
        deck2.shuffle();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            System.out.println(deck2.deal());
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Cards {
    protected int rank;
    protected int suit;
    protected String[] sNames = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds"};
    protected String[] rNames = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

    public Cards(int rank, int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ("Your card is: "+rNames[rank-1]+" of "+sNames[suit-1]);
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know why it says that the method shuffle is lower cased. It is not. For some reason it copied over as lowercase. Geany shows that the method and my calling are capital Shuffle

Comment: Dude, believe the compiler.  If it tells you it's lower case, believe it.  Fix one or the other.  My recommendation is the follow the Sun Java coding convention and make method names lower case.

Comment: Duly noted. And it has been corrected. Both are lowercase, but the error still persists

Comment: Maybe errors persist, but it shouldn't be "Its keeps telling me that it can not find the symbol when pointing to Deck2.Shuffle() and Deck2.deal(). Any ideas why?"  Sorry, fix your compiler issues and come back when you can run the code.

Comment: As stated in another comment I fixed the compiler issue. It was a dumb stupid mistake on my part. I now have other non-compiler issues, but I believe I can fix those myself.

Comment: public Cards deal() {
        return (hasMoreCards() ? deck[++cardHold] : null);
    }

I am currently in a Java course at my college and have not gone over this syntax. So using this would be bad decision on my part. 
I also changed the hasCardsLeft to your suggestion and it returns null values after the first card. The way I had it before it worked properly. Though it was not completely random, it worked. And I just want to confirm there was nothing changed in the Cards class except for making it neater correct? It was neat, but copying it back and forth screwed it all up

Comment: It didn't screw anything up.  Looks fine to me.  More importantly, it runs.  Don't care just about you and your needs; consider it a teaching moment.  You might appreciate the new notation when you're up to it.

Comment: I do appreciate it, I was just stating that syntax is something I can not use for this project. But again, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are using an assignment operator in the `if` statement expression here:

```
if (cardHold = 0)
```

Replace with

```
if (cardHold == 0)
```

Comment: This wouldn't create the missing symbol message (probably evaluates as true) but nicely spotted.

Comment: That is a good catch, but no it does not solve my main problem.

Comment: Try cleaning your project & recompile. Also you have another problem when you attempt to call shuffle. `cardHold` is `-1` which will lead to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: yes I just solved my own problem with the compiler. I just ran into that error, but I feel like I can work around that! Thanks for everyones help even though it was my dumb mistake

Answer (score 0):

you may want to add import java.util.Date; and the shuffle function and call in the main is different one have 's'and the other 'S'.

Comment: I might be missing something, but how did `java.util.Date` come into the picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Random;

public class DeckOfCards {

    private Cards[] Deck;
    private int cardHold;
    private Random rand;

    public DeckOfCards() {
        rand = new Random();
        Date d = new Date();
        rand.setSeed(d.getTime());
        Deck = new Cards[52];
        int n = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
                Deck[n] = new Cards(i, j);
                n = n + 1;
            }
        }
        cardHold = 0;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        // shuffles ands resets deck
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 52) {
            // int rando = (int)(5.0 * (Math.random()));
            int rando = rand.nextInt(52);
            Cards temp = Deck[rando];
            Deck[rando] = Deck[i];
            Deck[i] = temp;
            i++;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasMoreCards() {
        // returns true if there are more cards left, else return false
        if (cardHold == 0)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DeckOfCards Deck2 = new DeckOfCards();
        Deck2.shuffle();
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            System.out.println(Deck2.Deck[i]);

    }
}
```